# How do I install PortAudio on Windows?

Tags: python, github, pycharm, pyaudio, portaudio

## What I want to do:

I want to convert my voice input into text output in my python program (using PyCharm IDE),
I have successfully installed PyAudio but my program didn't function, then I realize I need PortAudio on my PC, but I don't have a clue how to install it,

## What I tried:

I downloaded the `pa_stable_v190700_20210406.tgz` file, from the official portaudio website which also got a link to its GitHub,
I am new to GitHub and I am very confused, can you guide me step by step on how to install PortAudio to my PC?

Comment: Hi Aryan welcome to the stack overflow, please include the error while running the code. If you install pyaudio using this command `python -m pip install pyaudio` portaudio is already installed as a dependency package on windows. you can refer the documentation here `https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/`

Comment: Thanks for the help, this package also resolved any requirements I hade with PyAudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all you are trying to do Is speech to text this simple code should work, first run `pip install SpeechRecognition` then this code should work

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Listening...")
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("Recognizing...")
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("You said:", text)
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Sorry, I could not understand your speech.")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Sorry, an error occurred. {0}".format(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @bhogan2017 for your code.

I try it from Pycharm IDE but got an error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\renato\Documents\mvp_1\reconocimiento_voz.py", line 7, in <module>
    audio = r.listen(source)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\renato\Documents\entornos\mvp_1\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 465, in listen
Listening...
    assert source.stream is not None, "Audio source must be entered before listening, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: Audio source must be entered before listening, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\renato\Documents\mvp_1\reconocimiento_voz.py", line 5, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "C:\Users\renato\Documents\entornos\mvp_1\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 189, in __exit__
    self.stream.close()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

**RESOLVED**
I solved the problem by uninstalling my Kaspersky antivirus. The problem was the firewall of this antivirus. I uninstalled it because I had no way to disable it, but surely disabling it will also correct the problem.

I tried uninstalling the antivirus because I read it in a comment in the following link: https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/423#issuecomment-531973098